# Vuetify dynamic img not working => ../assets/

Tags: image, vue.js, url, vuetify.js, src

I would like to v-for on an array that I want to get the **image** and text.

Image inside Data() {} I tried:

```
@/../assets/image.jpg
../../assets/image.jpg
~/..assets/image.jpg
require('../assets/image.jpg')"
```

Don't work at all.
If I 'hard coded' the image **inside the template** like below it works.

```
v-img(src='../assets/image.jpg')
```

When I split between Template and Data like below:

TEMPLATE:

```
<v-content>
  <v-container>
    <v-row>
      <v-col v-for="benefit in benefits"><img :src="benefit.icon" /></v-col>
    </v-row>
  </v-container>
</v-content>
```

SCRIPT:

```
export default {
  data() {
  return {
    benefits: [
      {
        icon: '../assets/image.jpg',
      },
```

Never works :(

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Does your backend know that `assets` is a static directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The template part of your code is not clear, however, from my understanding of what you are trying to achieve, this should work:

```
<template>
  <v-container>
    <v-row v-for="(benefit, index) in benefits" :key="index">
      <v-col>
        <v-img :src="benefit.icon" />
      </v-col>
    </v-row>
  </v-container>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      benefits: [
        { 
          icon: require('@/assets/image.jpg')
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Billal. That works. The only issue is that es-lint ('@vue/airbnb') complained about import/no-unresolved and global-require.

Comment: Add `{commonjs: true}` to your configuration file